# Unable to access stored procedures on localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Have been trying to get this to work for about an hour with no luck. I have copied my database from my hosting to my local machine and changed the connection string, but for some reason I keep getting this error:

`Could not find stored procedure`

It is connection to the right database and I can execute the stored procedures when I connect through management studio, so I don't know what is wrong. How do I debug this?

Thanks.

Here is the code, but remember that this works fine on the hosting's server:

```
private void openDatabaseConnection()
{
    myConnection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
    myCommand = new SqlCommand();
    myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
    myCommand.Parameters.Clear();
    myConnection.Open();
}

    using (myConnection)
    {
        openDatabaseConnection();
        using (myCommand)
        {
            myCommand.CommandText = "storedProcedureName";
            myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            using (myReader)
            {
                myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

                myReader.Read();
                //Get Data
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: How are you calling it from code currently?

Comment: The same I was calling it when it was on my hosting, I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: Check you have the correct default schema

Comment: I have no problems accessing SP from localhost. Show code please :)

Comment: check your connection string again or check if your local database has the particular stored procedure

Comment: "I can execute the stored procedures when I connect through management studio" - Is this using the same credentials as in your connection in the code? Bear in mind that logging into a database through management studio using your account may not give the same permissions as your code is getting.

Comment: Yes it is the same account. After a clean re-install it still gives the same error so I gave up.

Answer (score 1):

When you copy a database from one server to another you need to set the **Owner** of the database on the destination server, if you are using an SQL Server account to run your stored procedure then you need to set the owner of the database to that account.

In order to change the owner follow this steps:

1. Right click on the database, select Properties
2. Go to Files tab
3. On the right of the owner textbox is a button, click on it
4. Select from the SQL accounts the account that your app is using to access the database

Comment: Yes, this is a real pain, but I'm not sure that this result in the error stated by the OP

Comment: Can you provide instructions on how to do this please? I have no idea how. When I click on properties for the database it shows `Owner` as blank.

Comment: I tried to reinstall, and a I also set the owner of the database to my account. It still doesn't work; I give up.